# How to Retrieve tables of a database in a ComboBox using an windows form application?

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox, data-retrieval

This is the code, I used for adding database tables. Its working but I want to show the added tables name in a `comboBox`.
For an example: If I add a `schoolName1` into the database, how can I show the `schoolName1` in to `comboBox` ?. Thanks.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string myConnectionString= @"DataSource =.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=myconnection.mdf;Integrated Security=true;"

    SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);

    string myCommand = "CREATE TABLE["+textBox1.Text+"] (column1 VARCHAR(10),colunm2 INT)";

    SqlCommand dbConnection = new SqlCommand(myCommand,dbConnection);

    try
       {
          dbConnection.Open();
          dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }

    catch{}

          dbConnection.Close();
 }
```

Comment: Do you want to bind the combobox ?

Comment: Hey No man someone named Parta edited my codes now i cannot set it to what i actually asked.

Comment: actually i want to know how to bind database table names into an combobox.

Comment: Refer this: http://csharp-guide.blogspot.com/2012/06/binding-data-to-combobox-in-c-windows.html

Comment: hey Parta I by mistakenly accepted your editing. Don't give negative marks please. My reputation point is decreased already. I request you to remove it.

Comment: and i want to show the table names not tables information. please understand

Comment: I cannot give that negative and I didn't :). This is marked down since you get direct answer in google and still you posted here.

Comment: ok +1 , make ur questions always clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Retrieve all database tables 
you need to make query from information_schema.tables and bind results to desired combox

```
    String strConnection = "Data Source=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;database=your_db;Integrated Security=true";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
    try
    {

        con.Open();

        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

        sqlCmd.Connection = con;
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "Select table_name from information_schema.tables";

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

        DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
        sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
        comboBox1.DataSource = dtRecord;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

This is my way 
you can use several ways to retrieve this information and show in combobox
reference : [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/559881/displayplusnamesplusofplusallplustablesplusinpluss)

I have edited and complete your code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string myConnectionString = @"DataSource =.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=myconnection.mdf;Integrated Security=true;"

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillCombo();
        }

        private void FillCombo()
        {
            SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
            try
            {

                sqlCmd.Connection = dbConnection;
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                sqlCmd.CommandText = "use database_name; SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE';";
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
                DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
                sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
                comboBox1.DataSource = dtRecord;
                comboBox1.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            dbConnection.Close();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);
            string myCommand = "CREATE TABLE["+textBox1.Text+"] (column1 VARCHAR(10),colunm2 INT)";
            SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand(myCommand, dbConnection);
            try
               {
                  dbConnection.Open();
                  dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                  FillCombo();
               }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            dbConnection.Close();
         }
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi Farshad, comboBox1.dispalyMember="Table_Name"; is this will show all my database tables?

Comment: comboBox1.DisplayMember line used to define which field of schematic query result must show in combobox element

Comment: Yes, But Did it show my all tables in it? after creating the table how to refresh it? and how to show it in comboBox1?

Comment: place the code as a function right after creation of the new tables

Comment: Its getting an error Farshad, after created table successful. its showing invalid object name 'information_schema.tables'.

Comment: Its your choice to place this code right after insert new tables or define class or make seprate public function or class. your issue was how to How to Retrieve tables of a database in a ComboBox using an windows form application.

Comment: I am getting an error, I m not able to get the database Tables in comboBox1, I m getting error like this: Invalid object name 'information_schema.tables'.

Comment: try use database before make query for schematic update your query to `use database_name; SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE';`